# Read CSV File with some EOL missing

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, eol

I need to read a bunch of csv files to pandas dataframes, and I am running into some files which have a missing end-of-line character. It just isn't there at all. `pandas.read_csv` won't read them because of the "different number of columns".

```
Time; A; B; C
12:00; 1; 2; 3
12:01; 4; 5; 6; 12:02; 7; 8; 9
12:03; 10; 11; 12
12:04; 13; 14; 15
```

Fortunately, all these errors are before the first column, so I could look for the time (there is no other column with time). In this case, I'd just need to insert a CR/LF before 12:02 and then read to the dataframe:

```
Time; A; B; C
12:00; 1; 2; 3
12:01; 4; 5; 6; 
12:02; 7; 8; 9
12:03; 10; 11; 12
12:04; 13; 14; 15
```

Is there an efficient way to do this before `read_csv()`?  Or do I need to first open each file, look through each line, replace, close, then read with pandas?

---

Using: python3.5.2 , pandas 0.22.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try pre-processing the csv if you have irregularities

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

res = []
with open(filename) as infile:             #Read CSV
    header = next(infile).split(";")       #Get Header
    for line in infile:                    #Iterate each line
        val = line.split(";")
        if len(val) == 4:                  #Check if 4 elements in each line
            res.append(val)
        else:
            res.extend( [val[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(val), 4)] )     #Else split it. 

df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=header)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     Time    A    B    C\n
0   12:00    1    2    3\n
1   12:01    4    5      6
2   12:02    7    8    9\n
3   12:03   10   11   12\n
4   12:04   13   14     15
```